# How to get Access to establish bluetooth connection with RxAndroidBle?

Tags: android, bluetooth, rx-java2, rxandroidble

I use RxAndroidBle in a project and I have the following use case :

- A third part component also uses RxAndroidBle in order to establish a connection and interact with a defined set of Ble GATT services. But It hides the RxBleConnection stream. So other parts of the app cannot share it().
- Other parts of the App wants to use some of the Ble GATT services (which are distinct of the precedent).

If I understand, all the RxAndroidBle library is stateless, so it is up to me to implement a shared connection pool in order to share the stream of RxAndroidBle connection between this 2 components? 
Or it exists a simpler way?

What I have Done :

Wrapped RxBle and some object in statefullWrapped :

As example RxBleDevice method :

```
The establishConnection wrapped method is :  @Override
public Observable<RxBleConnection> establishConnection(boolean autoConnect) {
    return Observable.defer(()->
            pool.getConnectionFromPool(wrappedDevice.getMacAddress(),
                    wrappedDevice.establishConnection(autoConnect)
                            .doFinally(()-> pool.removeConnectionFromPool(wrappedDevice.getMacAddress()))
                            .compose(ReplayingShare.instance()))
    );
```

}

And the pool is have a concurrent map where we can retrieve Connection as :

```
public Observable<RxBleConnection> getConnectionFromPool(String macAddress,Observable<RxBleConnection> persistentConnection){
    Observable<RxBleConnection> previousConnection = connectionPoolMap.putIfAbsent(macAddress,persistentConnection);
    if (previousConnection != null){ // The connection is already established
        return previousConnection;
    }
    return persistentConnection;
```

}

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong — you want to intercept a connection that is established to a peripheral by a third party module? I am not really sure what you mean by `to implement a shared connection pool` — could you elaborate?

Comment: The use case is the following : the bluetooth device use have to service : one for log , one for Business operation. And the application wants to use twice and rely on an external third part library to abstract the business operation. But in application lifecycle no one can predict which of the component (logger abstraction or business abstraction) will establish the connection first. Fortunatly both use DI pattern of the RxBleClient. So what i have done is to build a new RxBleStatefull client that keep a pool of connection in a concurrentMap of MacAdress/stream.